# Bitwise operations between every pair of elements in array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, bit-manipulation, vectorization

Here is the situation:

I have a graph type structure, an adjacency list, and each element of this adjacency list is a 1 dimensional array (either numpy, or bcolz.. not sure if I will use bcolz or not).

Each 1-dimensional array represents graph elements that could possibly connect, in the form of binary sequences. For them to connect, they need to have a specific bitwise intersection value.

Therefore, for each 1 dimensional array in my adjacency list, I want to do the bitwise "and" between every combination of two elements in the given array.

This will possibly be used for huge graph breadth-first traversal, so we may be talking a very very large number of elements.

Is this something I can do with vectorized operations?  Should I be using a different structure?  What is a good way to do this? I am willing to completely restructure everything if there could be a significant performance boost.

Is it as simple as looping through the individual elements and then broadcasting(correct terminology?) & against the entire array?  Thanks.

**quick edit**

As an extra note, I am using python integers for my byte sequences.  Which from my understanding, doesn't play well with numpy(the integers get too big, type long long).  I have to create arrays of object type.  Does this potentially cause a huge slowdown?  Is it a reason to use a different structure?

**An Example**

> //create an nxn adjacency list, where n is number of graph nodes.
>   //map each graph node to a value 2^k:

```
nodevals = defaultdict()
for i in xrange(n):
    nodevals[i] = 2**(i+1)
```

> //for each edge in our graph it is comprised of two nodes, which are mapped as powers of two.  Take their sum, and place them in the adjacency list:

```
for i in xrange(n):
    for j in xrange(n):
        adjlist[i][j].append((nodevals[i]|nodevals[j]))
```

> //We now have our first Adjacency list, which is just bare edges.  These edges can be connected by row or column, by taking intersection of the sum (nodevals[i]|nodevals[j]) with the other edge (nodevals[i2]|nodevals[j2]), and checking if it equals the connection point for each.
>
> //this may not seem useful for individual edges, but in future iterations we can do this:
>
> //After 3 iterations.  (5,1) connected to (1,9),   and then this connected to (7,5), for example:

```
adjlist[5][1] & adjlist[1][9] == 1

adjlist2[5][9] == adjlist[5][1]|adjlist[1][9]

adjlist[7][5] & adjlist2[5][9] == 5

adjlist3[7][9] == adjlist[7][5]|adjlist2[5][9]
```

> //So, you may see how this could be useful for efficient traversal.
>   //However, it becomes more complicated, because as we increase the length of our subpaths, or "pseudo-edges", or whatever you want to call them,
>   //The arrays for the given (i,j) hold more and more subpath sums that can potentially be connected.
>   //Soon the arrays can become very large, which is when I would want to efficiently be able to calculate intersections
>
> //AND, **for this problem in particular, I want to be able to connect edges against the SAME edge, so I want to do the bitwise intersection between all pairs of elements in the given array** (ie, the given indices [i][j] of that adjacency list).

Comment: It would be helpful if you include your current code sample and small but illustrative examples of desired input / output.

Comment: Sure.  Well, this isn't actually the same as my old code.  But I'll write an example right now and put it into my description.

Comment: Start with the itertools `product` method on the list with itself?